# Dynamic jasper dependecy referenced twice apache commons-logging

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, dynamic-jasper

After the `dependency` update, the `message` is displayed on `SpringBoot` initialization:

> The Class-Path manifest attribute in
>   ...\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.0.3\commons-logging-1.0.3.jar
>   referenced one or more files that do not exist:
>   file:/.../.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.3/log4j.jar,file:/.../.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.3/log4j-core.jar

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
  <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.9</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I tried to download the jars manually or excludes the maven settings but I did not succeed.

Comment: Is this an error or just a warning?

Comment: It's a warning, however it freezes the SpringBoot initialization.